# Copying Files that have been modified in the last 5 days to a new folder

Tags: shell, find, cp

I need to copy files modified last 5 days in a folder. I am having this command

find /media/karunakar/Suppliers/xyz/ORD20130908 -name "*.DAT" -type f -mtime +5 -exec cp '{}' /media/karunakar/ord

it is not giving result

Comment: I guess using `... -exec cp {} /media/karunakar/ord/ \;` would make it.

Comment: it is not working ....find:missing argument to -exec

Comment: @user2795017 You need to have `\;` at the end of the command.  That is causing `missing argument to -exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(which find) $FOLDER_FROM_COPY -type f -mtime +5 -regex '$\|.*dat$\|.*DAT$' -print | xargs -I '{}' -P4 -n1 $(which cp) {} $FOLDER_TO_COPY
```

Comment: You can include multiple extensions, it uses 8 CPU's